# Can you please verify my robots.txt for wordpress

Tags: multisite, robots.txt

I am a newb in writing this and since this is dangerous stuff to fidlle with (if you are not sure what you are doing) can you please verify it?

I use wordpress multisite, this is why I chose to allow blogs.dir

I want only my posts and categories indexed. That's it:)

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /cron/
Disallow: /lo/
Disallow: /portfolio.html

Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-login.php

Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /wp-content/blogs.dir/

Disallow: /author/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /archives/
Disallow: /2010/*
Disallow: /2011/*
Disallow: /2012/*
Disallow: /about/

Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: */trackback
Disallow: /comments
Disallow: */comments
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.inc$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.gz$
Disallow: /*.wmv$
Disallow: /*.cgi$
Disallow: /*.xhtml$
Disallow: /*.xlsx $
Disallow: /*.doc$
Disallow: /*.pdf$
Disallow: /*.zip$

# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*
```

Ty, take care;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file *robots.txt* doesn't exclude all the search engines to crawl your site... Most search engines crawl the hole site without taking the *robots.txt* file in consideration.

I think that the best way is to use meta tags in the theme of the blogs.

Use the next meta tags for post and categories template files:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
<meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow" />
```

Use this meta tags for the rest of the template files

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As for robots.txt file. This will work with major search engines (Google, Bing/Yahoo, Yandex, Baidu).

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *.php
Disallow: *.js
Disallow: *.inc
Disallow: *.css
Disallow: *.gz
Disallow: *.wmv
Disallow: *.cgi
Disallow: *.xhtml
Disallow: *.xlsx
Disallow: *.doc
Disallow: *.pdf
Disallow: *.zip
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /author/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /archives/
Disallow: /2010/*
Disallow: /2011/*
Disallow: /2012/*
Disallow: /about/
Disallow: /trackback
Disallow: */trackback
Disallow: /comments
Disallow: */comments
Disallow: /feed
Disallow: */feed
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
Allow: /wp-content/blogs.dir/
Sitemap: http://domain.com/post_sitemap.xml
Crawl-delay: 4
```

Make sure you include a sitemap that only has posts. [Yoast's Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) can do this.

Finally (if you don't have a SEO plugin) add the following to your page template:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

And this to your post template

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```